# Big O Question - Algorithmic Analysis

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I am revising for an exam and I have found this problem on the internet and was wondering how I would go about solving it.

> (With base 2 logs)
>   Prove that log(2*n*) is a member of O(log *n*).

I have given it a go but am not sure if I am right as no answer has been provided. Could you please help?

Here is my attempt:

> log 2*n* - *c* log *n* ≤ 0
>   log 2 + log *n* - *c* log *n* ≤ 0
>   1 + (1-*c*) log *n* ≤ 0
>   (I then divided by the log *n*.)

Example: *n* = 8 and *c* = 10 evaluates to less than zero. Therefore it is **true**.

My questions are:

1. Am I doing this right?
2. Can my answer be simplified further?

Comment: -1, there's no need to insult other people; also, larsmans's answer is as concise and correct as it gets.

Comment: You want to prove that log(2n) is O(log(n)). Since log(2n) = log(2) + log(n) and lower order terms (log(2) in this case) can be ignored in asymptotic analysis, the result follows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long answer is that

```
                log(2n)       log(2) + log(n)       log(2)
lim n->infinity ------- = lim --------------- = lim ------ + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
                log(n)        log(n)                log(n)
```

Because the ratio of the two functions in the limit exists (i.e. is bounded), they have the same asymptotic complexity.

In the same way, to prove that O(n<sup>2</sup>) is not O(n), you would do

```
lim n->infinity (n^2 / n) = lim n    which tends to infinity
```

Doing this for O(n) vs. O(log n) requires more work because

```
lim n->infinity (n / log n)
```

needs to be handled somehow. The trick is then that you can use the derivatives instead, as the derivatives in the limit also need to be asymptotically related (otherwise their integrals are not, i.e. the original functions). You take the derivative of n, which is 1, and that of log n, which is n<sup>-1</sup>, after which

```
lim n->infinity (1 / (1 / n)) = lim n    which tends to infinity
```

Answer (score 7):

`lg(2n) = lg(2) + lg(n).`

lg(2) is a constant. See Wikipedia, [Logarithmic identities](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Algebraic_identities_or_laws).

Comment: Hmm - I am not sure where you got the lg(2) from at the end. lg(2n) = lg(2)+lg(n) surely....

Comment: Its a new sentence. It is not part of the former equation :)